# auto adjusting UI elements for iphone4S and iphone5

Tags: ios, iphone-5, autoresize, iphone-4

After a long search for how to display UI elements correctly on both iphone4S and iphone5.I am now confused as whats the best way to display UI elements in the Xib.Should I use autoresizing Feature in size inspector or should I use auto layout?If I use autoresizing, the image gets distorted.
Moreover ,I have also seen people doing the below

```
NSString *filename = @"image.png";
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenRect.size.height == 568.0f)
        filename = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@"-568h.png"];

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
```

Can anybody assist me as how should I proceed with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method is right but this code will be more cleaner way to put this.

```
NSString *filename;
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        filename = @"image.png";
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,400,300);
    } else {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);
    }
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
```

And also if you want to change size of imageview accordingly to the iPhone than also you can use this code.

Comment: How can I change the size of the imageview. Are you telling me to do this by code?Moreover,won't this be tedious to do if I have 15-20 imageView in one xib?

Comment: Could you tell me how do I change the size of the different UI elements (say e.g. UIButton) depending on the iPhone model?

Comment: you have to use CGRect method to create custom frame of your imageview or button see my code i have edited it. and use different value for different screen.